# If everything is an object in JS, then for each constructor must be a constructor because each constructor is an object. Does this have an end?

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking about several things that I couldn't find a clear answer for them although I read a lot of articles on websites and watched a lot of videos on Youtube.

1. I've heard that everything is an object except the primitive types if they don't define with the 'new' keyword. When I create a function, I know that the built-in 'Function' method is called along with the 'new' keyword and a function will be created. But that 'Function' method is also a function and therefore is an object and must have a constructor and the constructor of Function must have another constructor. This thing reminds me of the concept that if we are created by God, who created the God and who created the God of God and so on and so forth. Is there any end?
2. I know that there are three reference types in JavaScript: Objects, Functions, and Arrays. If everything is an object in Javascript, the functions and arrays are also objects. So why do we even need to separate the functions and arrays in reference types and show them as independent of the Object data type?

Comment: I think this is a more suitable question for StackExchange https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: `Object` is the "god" of Javascript, with the exception of `null`. *Nothing*  doesn't have a god is somehow fitting, I feel.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: That's a general conundrum in languages like this where *everything is [some thing]* but that thing itself must thereby also be *[some thing]*. So don't worry about it too hard, it just needs to work in practice, and internally it's rigged in some way that it makes the normal use cases "work".

Comment: An object can have `null` as its prototype, which is the case for the `Object.prototype` object so that's where it ends. Where are you getting the idea that JS arrays are a different reference type? JS arrays are just objects (but the language has some special syntax for instantiation).

Comment: Question 2 is based on a mistaken understanding that there are 'three reference types'. [Functions are just callable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#normal_objects_and_functions), and [arrays are "regular objects for which there is a particular relationship between integer-keyed properties and the length property"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#indexed_collections_arrays_and_typed_arrays). The MDN docs are a good place to clarify confusing and wrong info from other websites.